# IndexError: list index out of range in Django Debug View

Tags: python, django

We updated our Django and Python versions to 3.0.6 and 3.8 respectively. Everything seems fine even when we run into Exceptions or errors locally everything is fine.

However, whenever we run into issues on the server, we receive a basic "Internal Server Error" HTML page with no other content.

We have a custom 500 page for showing errors so we can get a general idea of what the Exception is, however we cannot see the debug page that Django normally shows when DEBUG is set to True.

Looking at the logs I can see that the exception is indeed thrown by whatever runs into the problem, however the debug view itself throws it's own Exception which I'd imagine is why we receive the default "Internal Server Error" page, as Django resorts to that when it can't render the Debug page.

The stack trace is:

```
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 333, in get_traceback_html
    c = Context(self.get_traceback_data(), use_l10n=False)
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 264, in get_traceback_data
    frames = self.get_traceback_frames()
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 424, in get_traceback_frames
    pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(
  File "/home/donationstore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 383, in _get_lines_from_file
    context_line = source[lineno]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Looking through that debug file in the Django code shows a couple of things:

- The function in question takes a number of parameters, however it seems like it tries to take either the file that the problem occured on or the module as a source and tries to split it
- I'd imagine this has something to do with how it renders the lines on the debug page under the main yellow box
- I feel like it hits a line (that is probably represented in the code somewhere) and because of how it is structured or padded or whatever, it tries to access too much from that list, in turn throwing that error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: as you said, the issue is caused by accessing parameters, did you tried using accepting parameters from ```**kwargs``` wherever you feel it is caused?

Comment: It's not so much an issue of where I am accessing them. Django itself is causing the index out of range exception because whatever is being passed into it is too small. I don't pass data into it, it's done automatically by Django, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what might be being passed in.